# DB2 error on TSQL

Tags: sql-server, db2, linked-server

I am getting this error: [OLE/DB provider returned message: [IBM][CLI Driver] [DB2 / linuxx8664] SQL0206N "LS_SCHEDULED_DATE" is not valid in the context where used. SQLSTATE=42703)
OLE DB error trace [OLE /DB Provider 'MSDASQL' IColumnsInfo: GetColumnsInfo returned 0x80004005:
Msg7339, Level 1, State 1, Line 83
OLE DB provider 'MSDASQL' reported an error.

---

The code I am getting this error is as follows:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp1') is not null begin drop table #Temp1

select * 

into #Temp1
from openquery(LnkServer,

'
Select 
X.loan_number, 
X.ls_code,
x.ls_actual_completion_date
x.ls_scheduled_completion_date

,max(Case WHEN (ls_code = ''924'' and ls_scheduled_completion_date <> (''01/01/1900'')
             then ls_scheduled_completion_code
               else NULL End) as Ls_scheduled_completion_date

,max(Case WHEN (ls_code = ''926'' and ls_scheduled_completion_date <> (''01/01/1900'')
             then ls_scheduled_completion_code
               else NULL End) as Ls_scheduled_completion_date

,max(Case WHEN (ls_code = ''927'' and ls_scheduled_completion_date <> (''01/01/1900'')
             then ls_scheduled_completion_code
               else NULL End) as Ls_scheduled_completion_date

,max(Case WHEN (ls_code = ''928'' and ls_scheduled_completion_date <> (''01/01/1900'')
             then ls_scheduled_completion_code
               else NULL End) as Ls_scheduled_completion_date

from master x
     inner join(select loan_number, MAX(ls_scheduled_completion_date) as COMPL_DATE
                MAX(ls_actual_completion_date) as APPROVAL_DATE

     Where LS_code in (''924'', ''926'', ''927'', ''928'', ''D08'', ''H38'', ''H79'', ''H42'',
                       ''M40'', ''M29'', ''M10'', ''M40'', ''P31'', ''P49'', ''S17'')

      Group by loan_number order by loan_number) y
      on x.loan_number = y.loan_number
         and x.ls_scheduled_date = y.Compl_date
         and x.ls_actual_completion_date = y.approval_date
      Group by x.loan_number, x.ls_actual_completion_date, ls_scheduled_date

for fetch only with ur')
```

Comment: to format code, select it in the editor and press Control-K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you mean `LS_SCHEDULED_COMPLETION_DATE`?

There doesn't appear to be a `LS_SCHEDULED_DATE` anywhere in the query other than in the `on` and `group by` clauses where I'm assuming the error is occurring.

From IBM's own `publib` [site](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00206n.html):

> For a SELECT or DELETE statement, the specified column is not a column of any of the tables or views identified in a FROM clause in the statement.
>
> Verify that the names are specified correctly in the SQL statement. For a SELECT statement, ensure that all the required tables are named in the FROM clause.

Comment: No probs. I like DB2 but it's error messages seem to have a fairly low signal-to-noise ratio :-)

Comment: I am also struggling to get this code to write one row per loan with potential of code/dates.

 In example: loan_number
(0000034), ls_code(924), ls_actual_completion_date(2008-05-07 00:00:00, ls_scheduled_completion_date(2008-09-27 00:00:00), STEP924_COMPL_DATE(2008-05-19 00:00:00), STEP926_COMPL_DATE(2008-05-19 00:00:00), 
STEP927_COMPL_DATE(2008-05-29 00:00:00), STEP928_COMPL_DATE (NULL),
ACTUAL_COMPL_DATE(NULL) APPROVAL_DATE(2008-06-01 00:00:00)

Of course the column names are across with corresponding dates below the appropriate column.

Comment: Paxdiablo, I have checked the code and do not see misspelled names. The required tables are in the from clause..

Comment: @JMS49, that sounds like a different problem (more to do with SQL than misspelling) and one that is hard to communicate in a small unformatted comment box (at least I'm having a hard time understanding it). I would suggest starting another question for it so it gets a better response than just me looking at it.

Comment: I found that the file Master was misspelled within the inner join statement.